# marquee tag start over loop hast too much delay time

Tags: html, wordpress, marquee

I am using marquee tag to display almost 30 WordPress posts, But when a loop finished restart marquee tag has too much delay time. What should I need to do start over after 3 seconds at first post?

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" onmouseover="this.stop()" onmouseout="this.start()">
  <?php  
$portfolio = new WP_Query(array(
'post_status' =>'publish',
'post_type' =>'post',
's' => 'ایران',
'posts_per_page' => '20',
'paged' => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1        
)); if($portfolio->have_posts()) : 
while($portfolio->have_posts()) : $portfolio->the_post();?>
  <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" target="_blank"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

  <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
  i'm using marquee tag to display almost 30 wordpress posts.but when a loop finished restart marquee tag has too much delay time.what should i do to start over after 3 seconds at first post?!
</marquee>
```

You can see results in http://akhbartop.ir/

Answer (score -1):

Please try

```
loop="infinite"
```

inside the marquee tag.

Comment: no its not related to restart loop because loop infinite is default for marquee tag.my problem is delay time to begin again